# How can I stack plots so that they are aligned nicely?

Tags: plotting, graphics

Suppose that I have two plots (e.g., `Plot`, `ListPlot`, etc) that cover two regions of space.  I would like to display them "stacked" vertically, so that they align nicely in publication-quality form.

Suppose that I am dealing with `ListPlot` and I have the following data:

```
xdata = Range[0, 2 Pi, 0.2];
ydata1 = Sin[xdata];
ydata2 = 1 + Sin[xdata];
```

So for plot1, I will plot `Transpose[{xdata, ydata1}]`; for plot2, I will plot `Transpose[{xdata, ydata2}]` (both using `ListPlot`).  Plot1 covers both negative and positive $y$ values, whereas plot2 covers only positive $y$ values; this fact will be important later.  For both plots, I will use `BaseStyle -> {18, FontFamily -> "Arial"}` so that the labels are large and legible.  I will also use `Frame -> True` and will include frame labels with `FrameLabel -> {"x (Meter)", "y (Meter)"}`.

Now if I do the following...

```
plot1 = ListPlot[Transpose[{xdata, ydata1}], Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"x (Meter)", "y (Meter)"}, 
  BaseStyle -> {18, FontFamily -> "Arial"}, PlotStyle -> Red, ImageSize -> 375]

plot2 = ListPlot[Transpose[{xdata, ydata2}], Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"x (Meter)", "y (Meter)"}, 
  BaseStyle -> {18, FontFamily -> "Arial"}, PlotStyle -> Blue, ImageSize -> 375]
```

...I get the following...

[image: Image1]

Notice that above, the frames are not aligned.  To fix this, I can specify the same `ImagePadding` for both plots...

```
plot1 = ListPlot[Transpose[{xdata, ydata1}], Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"x (Meter)", "y (Meter)"}, 
  BaseStyle -> {18, FontFamily -> "Arial"}, PlotStyle -> Red, ImageSize -> 375,
  ImagePadding -> {{70, 10}, {55, 10}}]

plot2 = ListPlot[Transpose[{xdata, ydata2}], Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"x (Meter)", "y (Meter)"}, 
  BaseStyle -> {18, FontFamily -> "Arial"}, PlotStyle -> Blue, ImageSize -> 375,
  ImagePadding -> {{70, 10}, {55, 10}}]
```

...which gives me the following output...

[image: Image2]

Now the frames are nicely aligned.  ***However***, the $y$ axis frame labels are not aligned.  This is because plot1 includes negative $y$ values in addition to positive ones, and the negative signs "push away" the $y$ axis frame label (i.e., `"y (Meter)"`) in plot1.

So, ***my question is:*** is it possible to somehow align the $y$ axis frame labels?  Apparently, `ImagePadding` does not do the trick for that particular issue.  Thanks for your time.

Comment: This is hardly noticeable ... Could you put y-label on the right perhaps? `FrameLabel -> {"x (Meter)", None, None, "y (Meter)"}`

Comment: Bad trick #2: `FrameTicks -> {Automatic, {{.5, "+\[VeryThinSpace]0.5"}}}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`Labeled`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Labeled.html) to label the frame.  Then the `ImagePadding` trick will work.

```
xdata = Range[0, 2 Pi, 0.2];
ydata1 = Sin[xdata];
ydata2 = 1 + Sin[xdata];
imsize = 375;
impad = {{40, 10}, {25, 10}};

plot1 = Labeled[
  ListPlot[Transpose[{xdata, ydata1}], Frame -> True, 
   BaseStyle -> {18, FontFamily -> "Arial"}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
   ImageSize -> imsize, ImagePadding -> impad],
  {"x (Meter)", "y (Meter)"}, {Bottom, Left}, RotateLabel -> True, 
  LabelStyle -> {18, FontFamily -> "Arial"}
  ]

plot2 =
 Labeled[
  ListPlot[Transpose[{xdata, ydata2}], Frame -> True, 
   PlotStyle -> Blue, BaseStyle -> {18, FontFamily -> "Arial"}, 
   ImageSize -> imsize, ImagePadding -> impad],
  {"x (Meter)", "y (Meter)"}, {Bottom, Left}, RotateLabel -> True, 
  LabelStyle -> {18, FontFamily -> "Arial"}
  ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]